# Error: could not find function "rsDriver" : RSELENIUM

Tags: r, rselenium

Hi I am trying to connect website through R selenium package with the below code

```
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::checkForServer()
RSelenium::startServer()

url <-  "http://google.com"
rD <- rsDriver(port=4444L,browser="chrome",remoteServerAddr="localhost")
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(url)
```

The error i am getting is could not find rsDriver function.
Please help to modify the above code

Comment: install.packages("Rselenium", dependencies = T)

Comment: run above line an then try again

Comment: Thanks ayush the same error i am getting